# Access mainpage content from other page loaded in frame

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm developing a program in C# & XAML where my MainPage has two frames, one of which is an entire page.

I want to load another page inside the Inner frame of MainPage, which has a number of buttons. By pressing one of them, I want to load the Third Page in my Whole Page Frame (bigger frame).

Any suggestions to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"frame" being the name of the frame you want your page to appear on and "ThirdPage" a page item of your project, you could add the code below to the button click event you are talking about:

```
frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new ThirdPage());
```

Comment: I tested your code but unfortunately third page load on inner frame , not the whole Page frame :(

Comment: The page will load on the frame that you called the Navigate() method on. Does your "whole page frame" have a Name attached to it? Imagine you declared your frame like this: <Frame Name="wholePageFrame"/>, then you only need the code to be: wholePageFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new ThirdPage());

Comment: It's true but the "WholePageFrame" doesn't show in .cs file, cause actually the WholePageFrame is a property of MainPage not this one

Comment: Done, Thank you Daniel